# Promise.all, but with enforced limit on concurrent promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm trying to implement `parallelLimit()` to limit the number of parallel tasks that can be performed at any time. Personally, I'm using this function for limiting the parallel uploads from my code.

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

async function _parallelLimit(tasks, limit) {
  const _tasks = Object.assign([], _.zip(tasks, _.range(tasks.length)));
  const results = [];
  const awaitWorker = async () => {
    while (_tasks.length > 0) {
      const [task, idx] = _tasks.pop();
      results[idx] = await task();
    }
  };
  await Promise.all(_.range(0, limit).map(awaitWorker));
  return results;
}
```

Comment: So, do you completely discard off-limit tasks instead of keeping them for a later execution?

Comment: uh, no, the off-limit tasks will get executed, the while loop will make sure that a worker when idle will execute the remaining task unless there are no tasks anymore

Comment: Hmm, `_tasks` is defined as `_.zip(tasks, _.range(limit))`. lodash's help says nothing about `zip`'s behavior when arguments have different lengths (is it common in JS world to not give any details on the library in its docs?), so I assume `_tasks` has length at most `limit`, which means all the elements of `tasks` beyond `limit` first are discarded, aren't they? `tasks` are never considered past the very first line of the function, and while loop has nothing to do with them.

Comment: uh, that's a bug, let me just update it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `Object.assign` as `_.zip` will eventually give you the required array.

Also `_.range(0, limit)` is equivalent to `_.range(limit)`.

Answer (score 1):

I really like that you are declaring every variable as `const`!

Some minor remarks:

- Sanity-check your inputs:

  ```
  if (!(Number.isInteger(limit) && limit >= 1)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid arguments passed to parallelLimit().\
   Limit must be an integer >= 1');
  }
  ```
- Clarity: specify the length of the results array: `const results = new Array(tasks.length)`.
  I don't know whether this pre-allocates anything in JS VMs, but it lets the reader know how many items you intend to put into the array.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that `new Array(tasks.length)` is clearer than `[]`. If you are coming from a Java (or similar) background, the familiarity might make it clearer to you... However I *really* don't like overloads, and the array constructor is overloaded in a way to make it easy to mess up if you don't pay close attention.`new Array('a')` => `['a']`, `new Array(1)` => `[ empty ]`, `new Array(1, 2)` => `[1, 2]`. If you really want to be explicit, I'd prefer `Array.from({ length: tasks.length })`

Comment: @Gerrit0 Indeed, these Array overloads are unfortunate. Point taken. I personally only use `new Array(variable)` (i.e. no magic number), for all other use cases I take the bracket syntax.